# Both socket and file recommended buffer size

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel

Please, Linux kernel hackers, what is a reasonable buffer size for `write(2)` syscall to sockets or files, performance-wise? It's clear that it's some pagesize multiple, but which one? Does it matter? What is "too small" and "too big"?

Comment: Anything less than 128 kilobytes, because that is what fits into the send queue by default (unless you want to play with setsockopt).

Comment: @Damon: I'm not sure that "anything" is a right answer. Buffers should be definitely aligned, at least.

Comment: The default works for most people most of the time (it's reasonable to assume that the people writing the network stack are not complete idiots). Unless you regularly need to send huge amounts of data (really huge) and have some strict constraints on latency, there is normally no reason to bother. Anything that's a "reasonable" size is simply copied into the send buffer and sent, no matter how much it is. If not all of it fits, `write` will write less than what you ask for (returning the amount). In any case, it just works.

Comment: Buffer alignment is important (or _may_ be) for example if you vmsplice/splice your data directly to the network card, because that allows the kernel to just remap the page and DMA off the page onto network, kind of. `write` makes a copy anyway, so... nobody cares.

Comment: @Damon: Yes, it works, I absolutely do agree. But that's not the answer. Moreover, I asked also about regular files.

Comment: Same thing for regular files. `write` makes a copy, fullstop. No alignment needed, no size constraints. If `write` doesn't have enough buffers for some terabytes that you throw at it, then it will return the number of bytes that it was able to write out, and you call `write` again, minus that amount.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

depends on how big your delay to the peer is, let's say you have a 100MBps connection, and a delay of 50ms, then you can calculate

```
100MBps * 0.050 sec / 8 = 0.625MB = 625KB
```

but the default window size in Linux 2.6 is around 110KB, which will limit your throught out to around 2.2MBps (110KB / 0.050)
so, to fix that you can you `setsockopt`

```
int ret, sock, buf_size;
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
buf_size = 625*1024;
ret = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *)&buf_size, sizeof(buf_size));
ret = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&buf_size, sizeof(buf_size));
```